# ymaps.Polygon + draggable: true только в Firefox

Tags: firefox, polygon, draggable

Доброго времени суток.

```
    // Опции многоугольника или линии.
    var styles = [
        {strokeColor: '#ff00ff', strokeOpacity: 0.7, strokeWidth: 3, fillColor: '#ff00ff', fillOpacity: 0.4, draggable: true}
    ];
            var geoObject = new ymaps.Polygon([coordinates], {}, styles[0]);
            MapFullFind.geoObjects.add(geoObject);
```

только в Firefox
При перетаскивании Polygon, попросту пропадает. Но тоже не всегда. Раз на раз не приходится. При сдвиге карты - появляется, на том месте куда передвинули. 
Не могу понять с чем это связано, подскажите куда копать? ситуация не однозначна, то пропадает то нет.